# Using Azure "Functional code search" how do I find a phrase

Tags: azure, search

I'm talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/functional-code-search?view=azure-devops

I'd like to find the string "this.Data =" (without the quotes). These are all typescript files (ext:ts).

I've tried all of the following and while they do find "this.Data" I'm never able to find **just** files that include the exact string "this.Data =".

In other words I have to filter through a lot of files before I find the one with the exact string I want.

1. strlit:"this.Data =" (I expect this to work)
2. "this.Data =" (I expect this to work)
3. strlit:this.Data = (I don't expect this to work)
4. strlit:this.Data/s= (I don't expect this to work without a regex mode)
5. this.Data = (I don't expect this to work)

What am I doing wrong?